# Subset a dataframe based on multiple columns simultaneously

Tags: r

Suppose I have two dataframes like

```
> r1 <- data.frame(replicate(5, sample(1:3, 5, replace = TRUE)))
> r2 <- data.frame(replicate(5, sample(1:3, 5, replace = TRUE)))

> r1
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1  2  3  1  3  1
2  1  3  1  1  3
3  3  2  3  3  3
4  1  1  1  2  3
5  1  1  3  2  3

> r2
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1  1  3  3  3  2
2  3  1  2  1  2
3  1  1  1  2  2
4  2  3  1  2  2
5  2  2  1  2  3
```

I would like to subset r1 so that the result would only contain rows where r1$X1 == r2$X1 AND r1$X2 == r2$X2 AND r1$X3 == r2$X3, e.g.

```
r1_example
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1  2  3  1  3  1
4  1  1  1  2  3
```

If I actually do subset, I'm getting more values, because some of the columns separately correspond to the r2 columns.

```
> r1_sub <- subset(r1, X1 %in% r2$X1 & X2 %in% r2$X2 & X3 %in% r2$X3)
> r1_sub
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1  2  3  1  3  1
2  1  3  1  1  3
3  3  2  3  3  3
4  1  1  1  2  3
5  1  1  3  2  3
```

I can figure a workaround like

```
> r1$concat <- paste(r1$X1, '&', r1$X2, '&', r1$X3)
> r2$concat <- paste(r2$X1, '&', r2$X2, '&', r2$X3)
> r1_concat <- subset(r1, concat %in% r2$concat)
> r1_concat
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5    concat
1  2  3  1  3  1 2 & 3 & 1
4  1  1  1  2  3 1 & 1 & 1
```

But that's crude to say the least. Is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can keep only the columns `X1` to `X3` in `r2` and `merge` the data :

```
merge(r1, r2[c('X1', 'X2', 'X3')])

   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
#1  1  1  1  2  3
#2  2  3  1  3  1
```

In `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
r2 %>% select(X1:X3) %>% inner_join(r1)
```

Answer (score 1):

using **semi_join**

```r
library(tidyverse)

r1 <- read.table(text = "  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1  2  3  1  3  1
2  1  3  1  1  3
3  3  2  3  3  3
4  1  1  1  2  3
5  1  1  3  2  3", header = T)

r2 <- read.table(text = "  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1  1  3  3  3  2
2  3  1  2  1  2
3  1  1  1  2  2
4  2  3  1  2  2
5  2  2  1  2  3", header = T)

semi_join(r1, r2, by = c("X1", "X2", "X3"))
#>   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
#> 1  2  3  1  3  1
#> 4  1  1  1  2  3
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>